# Ingesting data into HDFS using Nifi - can't access files

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi, hortonworks-sandbox

So, I'm using NiFi for the first time. I'm trying to use it to call an API and then to pipe the data into HDFS (Hortonworks Sandbox 2.4). I'm using just 2 processors currently: GetHTTP & PutHDFS.

I seem to have both processors configured ok... they run, but I can't then find the output file that's been created when I go into Hadoop through Ambari... I've set the output directory to be /user/, but nothing appears. However, I am getting a warning message on the PutHDFS processor advising:

```
WARNING PutHDFS[...] penalizing StandardFlowFileRecord[...] and routing to failure because file with same name already exists.
```

...so a file must be getting written somewhere. I've tried varying the API call specifying both xml and JSON formats, but makes no apparent difference.

I figure I must either need to add some processing to the pipeline in NiFi, or i'm looking in the wrong place in the sandbox. Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working. Built a dataflow comprising 4 processors:

- getHTTP
- evaluateXPath
- 2 x PutHDFS, one for 'matched', one for 'unmatched'

I think it was a case of correctly specifying the Auto Terminate Relationships (selecting both 'success' and 'failure' in the ).

Credit to http://nifi.rocks/getting-started-with-apache-nifi which provided the building blocks and thanks to others for comments.

Comment: I am doing the same thing. Can you tell me what putHDFS uses underwater? I cannot find that. A Spark job, sqoop? I'm architecting and not doing this myself this time.

Answer (score 3):

The PutHDFS processor reads the "filename" attribute on the incoming FlowFile and uses that as the filename in HDFS. As stated in the Documentation[1].

GetHTTP sets the "filename" attribute to be "..the name of the file on the remote server"[2]. So I'm guessing you're GetHTTP processor is getting the same file each time and thus the "filename" attribute will be the same on every FlowFile.

So in order to get around that error, you need an UpdateAttribute processor[3] which changes the "filename" attribute to a unique value.

[1] https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS/index.html

[2] https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetHTTP/index.html

[3] https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/index.html

Comment: Thanks @JDP10101. Take your points regarding the error resulting from subsequent files having the same title. I'll have a play with the UpdateAttribute processor to try and resolve this. I still have a question though regarding why I can't currently see the file in HDFS? Do you know why this might be, or once I've incorporated the UpdateAttribute processor to specify the file with a .xml extension, should it become visible in the output directory? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you SSH to the sandbox and run "hadoop fs -ls /user/" do you see the file? Typically you wouldn't put data directly in /user, you would have a sub-directory for a specific user.

Comment: Thanks @BryanBende but afraid not. When I list all the files within the directory, i'm not still not seeing the output. I've created a sub-directory `/user/maria_dev/MetFiles/` and configured the processor to output the file to this location, but i'm still not seeing anything when I SSH to the sandbox with PuTTy. Greatly appreciate suggestions for anything else I could try please.

Comment: So I've followed a mega-useful tutorial at http://www.nifi.rocks/getting-started-with-apache-nifi/ which basically lays out exactly what i'm looking to achieve. The data flow works perfectly (no error messages) BUT I'm still not able to find any output files in the sandbox HDFS... Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?